# How to select between two Beans with the same Property set

Tags: java

How do I change which Bean my code is looking at in a XML file. they have the same Property Set and Class but Different Values?

```
<bean id = "Test1" class = "Common.TestBuild">
    <property name="testName" value = "x"/>
    <property name="columnNumberA" value = "x"/>
    <property name="columnNumberB" value = "x"/>
    <property name="typeA" value = "x"/>
    <property name="typeB" value = "x"/>
    <property name="checkA" value = "x"/>
    <property name="checkB" value = "x"/>
    <property name="responceColunm" value = "x"/>
    <property name="responceValue" value = "x"/>
</bean>
<bean id = "Test2" class = "Common.TestBuild">
    <property name="testName" value = "b"/>
    <property name="columnNumberA" value = "b"/>
    <property name="columnNumberB" value = "b"/>
    <property name="typeA" value = "b"/>
    <property name="typeB" value = "b"/>
    <property name="checkA" value = "b"/>
    <property name="checkB" value = "b"/>
    <property name="responceColunm" value = "b"/>
    <property name="responceValue" value = "b"/>
</bean>
```

And I am building a Test list String Array in the code to do work.

```
public String[][] GetTestList(int ColumnCount, int TestCount)
{


    String TestList[][] = new String[TestCount][9];


    for (int i = 0; i < TestCount ; i++)
    {
   // code goes here for getter and setter calls but need to 
   // figure out how to change beans.
        TestList[i][0] = TestName;
        TestList[i][1] = ColumnNumberA;
        TestList[i][2] = ColumnNumberB;
        TestList[i][3] = typeA;
        TestList[i][4] = typeB;
        TestList[i][5] = CheckA;
        TestList[i][6] = CheckB;
        TestList[i][5] = ResponceColunm;
        TestList[i][6] = ResponceValue;
    }
    return TestList;
}
```

I have the Getter and Setter calls but not sure how to change which Bean to look at. Each congif file will have a different Number of Test Beans in it.

Comment: You can decide based on the `id attribute` . Which library are you using for parsing XML?

Comment: I am using Spring Framework 4.3.4

Comment: I have looked at annotations but the @Qualifier can not go into the for statement. I need to shift it through Test1, Test2, Test3....... TestN. to Run each test set based on the values in the Beans

Comment: I got the calls working by using lazy-init="true" and i just use a For statement to iterate through them. thank you.